# Get href from link above another element with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium and I need to get an `href` from a link that is above many tags!

But  the only information that I can use and I have for sure, is the text "Test text!" from the `h3` tag!
Here is the example:

```
<a href="/link/post" class="link" >
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="header flex">
        <h3 class="mb-0">
          Test text!
          </h3>
       </div>
     </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Did you try a XPATH like `h3/ancestor::a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following `xpath` to locate the desired element:

```
//a[@href and .//h3[contains(text(),'Test text!')]]
```

So, to get the `href` value you have to

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
href = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@href and .//h3[contains(text(),'Test text!')]]')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. @Maximilian Peters asnwer works as well.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the approach in Prophet's answer would be to use a XPATH like

```
//h3[contains(text(),"Test text!")]]//ancestor::a
```

i.e. first search for the `h3` tag and then for an `a` tag above.

Prophet's answer uses the opposite approach, first find all `a` tags and then only keep the one with the correct `h3` tag below.

Comment: I suggested what I suggested because I'm not sure what can be between the  desired `a` element with the `href` and the `h3` containing known text. In case there is some other `a` between them your approach will not work while my will. ;)

Comment: Your answer is perfectly valid in my opinion. Depending on the exact circumstances one might be more convenient than the other.

Comment: I definitely agree with you ;)
I think //h3[contains(text(),"Test text!")]]//ancestor::a[@href] would be similar to mine